# Getting the character printed by a key using the current keyboard layout

Tags: c#, .net

In C#, I'm trying to take a string, and change it to the string that would have been received if the user had clicked the same keys, but in a different keyboard layout. Example: if the user clicks "a" while in the en-US layout, they'll get the character "a". But if they do it in the he-IL layout, they'll get the Hebrew character ש.

I tried the following code:

```
var kc = new System.Windows.Forms.KeysConverter();
var result = kc.ConvertToString(null, new CultureInfo("he-IL"), Keys.C);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

...but all I got the string string `"A"`.

Does anyone know how to do this using .Net functions, **without** using the API ToUnicodeEx?

Comment: I'm not actually using this in a keypress event. I'm taking an entire string after it has been typed, and converting it to what should have been typed.

Comment: do you always want to take only English letters despite of she/he uses he-IL layout?

Comment: If you want to do this properly, you not only have to use `ToUnicodeEx`, you have to allow for dead keys, shift states, combining characters etc. If this is just for your use, you could just build up a map of the keyboard(s) you use, and use that.

Comment: A strange idea which came into my mind (and to tell this right from the beginning: I'm not used to multiple KB-layouts): You might puffer the last X key strokes (including all special keys). I'd do this in `ProcessCmdKey`. If you find you've typed with the wrong layout you could delete your input, switch the layout and repeat the key strokes from your puffer.

Comment: Thanks to everyone trying to help. @StepUp - no, I need to be able to switch between arbitrary languages.

Comment: @stuartd - thanks for the advice. I'm not sure I'll have to take shift states etc into account since I'm starting out with a string, so I'll have to, for example, take the character "a", convert it to its keycode, and from the keycode convert back to a character in the correct layout. But it seems I will have to use ToUnicodeEx after all.

Comment: @Shnugo - no idea is ever strange :-) I'm looking for something a little bit simpler and more generalized though. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: You need to switch between arbitrary language, but always take just English letters?

Comment: @StepUp - no, I need to change between any arbitrary language and any other arbitrary language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this perfectly, simply because part of the information is lost.

For example, in the czech keyboard layout, the key `2` gives `ě`. If I accidentally write using the english keyboard, I get `2` - but is that the numeric 2 (which is the same in czech layout) or was it supposed to be `ě`? In the other direction, my particular czech keyboard layout uses `Alt-Gr` (basically, `Ctrl+Alt`) to write english keyboard characters (for example, `{`) - if I use the same combination on an english keyboard, the result is *nothing*. Oops?

Another issue is that cultures do not map to keyboard layouts cleanly. First, there's three windows keyboard layouts for Czech to choose from, which each behave differently, but all fall in the same culture. Second, different (physical) keyboards can map different virtual keys to different physical keys, further complicating the issue.

In the end, you'll have to guess. And as long as you're guessing anyway, I'd suggest just making your own mapping tables that you could apply char-by-char. You can get from `Keys` to a `char` using P/Invoke, but you don't even have the `Keys` value to start with - all you have is a `char`. You could use simple functions to handle "common" characters (for example, czech and english usually have the same latin characters - `a` is `a` etc. - though in the most common layout, `z` is `y` and vice versa, so it's still tricky), but that probably isn't going to help with e.g. english vs. hebrew. This is *still* tricky, but it should get you close enough to enable manual corrections for whatever wasn't translated correctly.

And just as a note, `KeysConverter` only translates the *names* of the keys, it doesn't do any virtual keyboard mapping. It's useful when you want to translate `Keys.Control | Keys.Alt | Keys.Delete` to `Ctrl+Alt+Del` (or back), but that's about it.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to write down this detailed reply. I never thought about languages where the mapping wouldn't be 1:1. In Hebrew <-> English, the mapping is 1:1 (if you ignore upper-case/lower-case issues...). Google search does this: if I accidentally type an english word in a Hebrew layout, it will know what I mean, and vice versa. Of course Google also looks up the words in a database... Curiously, I tried this now based on your example, installed Czech, and wrote 34uke. It didn't recognize this as ščuke.

Comment: the point is that this is a convenience function, and if it only works %80 of the time, that's fine with me. At worst, users will just have to retype everything, which is what they'd have to do anyway. At best, sometimes it'll save them a few clicks.

Comment: @user884248 Yeah, I thought so - I'd just build a manual mapping table if I were you. Unless you need to support *all* the locales.

Answer (score 0):

I do not whether this solution is good. Maybe it is a really ugly solution, but I really want to share with community... You can throw to me tomatoes:))).

Let's consider that we have languages, for example, Russian and English language and WinForms application. In my view, we can create some key map for these languages. We know that:

1. e.KeyValue always equals English letter despite of keyboard
2. We know that e.KeyValue is always in Upper case

So we should create helper class. For example:

```
public class EnglishRussian
{
    public int IndexRussian { get; set; }
    public int IndexEnglish { get; set; }

    public char EnglishLetter { get; set; }
    public char RussianLetter { get; set; }

}
```

And to define the opposite key value, we use dictionary:

```
private void textBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
   Dictionary<char, EnglishRussian> letterDictionary = new Dictionary<char, EnglishRussian>();
   letterDictionary.Add('A', new EnglishRussian() {RussianLetter='ф', IndexRussian='ф', EnglishLetter='a', IndexEnglish='a' });
   //You need to add all English letters and their opposite Russian letters
   char ch = (char)e.KeyValue;       
   char yourValue;
   switch(ch)
   {
     case 'A':
        {
          yourValue= letterDictionary[ch].RussianLetter;
          break;
        }            
    }
}
```

Maybe it is not elegant solution, but my conscience is clear cause I really wanted to share with my thoughts and at least it works with one keyboard.